# Looping through collection causes lockup

Tags: xpages

I am doing a search then looping through the results.  This is causing my code to lock up and worse, it is locking up that database from any further use.  Even after the browser is closed. It seems this "lockup" is cleared after a period of time of course until I try my code again.    I am going to change the way I do this particular task but I was curious as to what is causing this lockup.

```
     var collection = database.search("Form = 'Request01' & Status='Approved'");

if (collection.getCount() == 0)
{
    getComponent("panel1").setRendered(false);
    getComponent("panel2").setRendered(true);
    getComponent("panel4").setRendered(true);
    return; 
}


dBar.info("Approved Requests Found= " + collection.getCount());

var item:NotesItem = document1.replaceItemValue("DocIds","AAAA");

var doc:NotesDocument = collection.getFirstDocument();

while (doc != null)
{   
    try
    {
        var tmpDoc = collection.getNextDocument(doc);
        item.appendToTextList(doc.getNoteID());
        dBar.info("Processing document: " + doc.getNoteID() )
        doc.recycle();
        doc = tmpDoc;

    }
    catch(e)
    {
        dBar.error(e.message);

    }
}
document1.save();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following line...

```
var item:NotesItem = document1.replaceItemValue("DocIds","AAAA");
```

... returns *void*, your variable *item* is undefined. The next operation with this

```
item.appendToTextList(doc.getNoteID());
```

throws an error and ends up always in your *catch*-Block. Then, the next document is **never** fetched, you have an infinite loop.

**EDIT**:
The *replaceItemValue* method normally returns the NotesItem, but not for a NotesXspDocument!

Comment: replaceItemValue is supposed to return an item, so I'm not certain that's the reason for the infinite loop, but Sven is right: the try should definitely be around the loop, not inside it.

Comment: @Tim: No, the *replaceItemValue* method of an *NotesXspDocument* returns *void*. For Java and LS, it returns the NotesItem instead.

Comment: Then how do you get a handle to the NotesItem?  Whay would they implment it like this?

Comment: I think they implemented it this way to prevent inconsistent data (think about the good old UI / Backend problem in oldschool notes applications). You can access the item this way: *document1.getDocument().getFirstItem("DocIds")*

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how many docs there are in your database. I see two potential issues:

1)
db.search is (in my opinion) not recommended to use as it causes performance issues. 
Not sure if it has to do with your issue but rather than using db.search I recommend using something else, e. g. a view with the selection formula that matches your query.

2) if your db has many docs matching your query the java code might cause issues. As far as I know you should not fetch more than 10k domino objects using java.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two ways to debug this.

Install XPages Toolbox on the server. Use the CPU profiler to see what takes the most time.

http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=openDocument&name=xpages%20toolbox

Rewrite the code to java, enable debugging on the server, and remotely debug.
Here's a video that shows you how to do it:

http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/Debug_Java_for_XPages_in_NSFs